# React-native : How to detect when a component is rendered / open / un functionnal component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

maybe it's a stupid question but i don't find a response ( i'm begining with react-native ).

I need to detect when a view is opened ( switch in a stack menu ) , my view is a component (function). If my View is opened I would to start a simple action/dispatch in redux.

I search with react-native router and Redux but I didn't find a solution.
I search with function component but If I use useMemo ( react ), this method is started one time.  Not one time per display of a component.

```
// my menu      

<Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'Home',
              tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused  }) => (
                  <Icon name={'home'} size={20} color={focused ? '#6646ee' : "#fff"} />
              ),
              tabBarOptions: { activeTintColor:'black' }
          }}
      />
```

If you have a solution , maybe is simple ...
thanks for advance

**Updated**:
Ok I find a solution to detect if i click in the menu

```
<Tab.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen2Class}
              options={{
                  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                  tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused  }) => (
                      <Icon name={'home'} size={20} color={focused ? '#6646ee' : "#fff"} />
                  ),
                  tabBarOptions: { activeTintColor:'black' }
              }}
              listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                  tabPress: e => {
                      console.log('page Home clicked')
                  }
              })}
```

Ok but How to dispatch a reducer in the tabPress
In a simple component i must to use it:

```
 const action = {type: 'ADD_TEST_2', value: 'blaseb'};
    props.dispatch(action);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a isOpen state and setting the state every time a view is opened, and dispatching an action based on the isOpen state? (not very confident myself in react native).

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

...
<View dispatch={isOpen ? dispatch(type: SOME_TYPE, payload }}) : null}>...</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-navigation, you can use the [useFocuseEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) hook.I think other router libraries should also provide some focus event like API to achieve the same func.